# Is there a memory leak here? Trying to pass object through a function

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I have following function:

```
int getNumber( MyObject &obj ) {
    .....
}
```

I can do like this:

```
MyObject obj; // obj.x = 10; obj.y = 20; ...setting up the object
if ( getNumber( obj ) > 35 ) { // something to do...
}
```

But when I try to do something like this:

```
MyObject getObj() { // i need to return an object here
    MyObject newObj; // setting up the object: newObj.x = .....
    return newObj;
}
if ( getNumber( getObj() ) > 35 ) {...}
```

I get a warning: **"Non-const lvalue reference to type 'MyObject' cannot bind to a temporary of type 'MyObject'"**. I can solve it like this:

```
MyObject obj = getObj();
if ( getNumber( obj ) > 35 ) {...}
```

But it's very uncomfortable to use. I wanna create another function and use it like this:

```
int getNumber2( MyObject obj ) {
    MyObject newObj; // now it's not a temporary variable I think :)
    return getNumber( newObj );
}
if ( getNumber2( getObj() ) {...}
```

Is there a memory leak problem here? Maybe there's some intresting ways to solve that warning? :)

Comment: There's no memory leak if you're not deleting that which you allocated with `new`/`new[]`. The problem is that you're trying to bind a temporary to a non-const reference.

Comment: You could simply make `getNumber` take a const ref, i think...assuming you don't need to modify the object.  (And if you did have to...then isn't passing a temporary kinda defeating the purpose?)

Comment: Inside the function, `newObj` is not temporary (since indeed it has a name), but the *return value* of the function evaluation is a temporary value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's telling you that when  you call `getNumber( getObj() )`, `getNumber` should not be allowed to modify the object.

To fix this try:

```
int getNumber(const MyObject &obj ) {
  // You code should not modify obj
}
```

BTW, there is no memory leak.

For your `int getNumber2( MyObject obj )`, I do not see the point of calling

```
int getNumber2( MyObject obj )
{
    MyObject newObj; // now it's not a temporary variable I think :)
    return getNumber( newObj );
}
```

It means that you do not bother the `MyObject` passed as parameter to `getNumber()`, because that's not the one `getNumber2` gets...

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply! It works :) I'll accept your answer in a few minutes.